# Get cart items woocommerce as array

Tags: php, arrays

I got this code:

```
global $woocommerce;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
$arr_product=array();
foreach($items as $item => $values) {             
    $arr_product[]= $_product->post_title;            
}
```

It returns:

> Array ( [0] => [1] => );

It should return the titles but instead I get these numbers. How do I solve this?

Comment: check what `var_dump($items)` contains.

Comment: returns nothing @Federkun

Comment: I'm using this code inside an array. this code itself is outside the array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use:

```php
    WC()->cart->get_cart();
instead of `$woocommerce->cart->get_cart();`
```